# Should tensile or compressive force be applied?

Tags: forces

When a railway is laid in a cold environment, should tensile or compressive force be applied? How does this work? I think the answer should be tensile. The railways expand while heated so applying tensile force would mean there is less extension and therefore less stress. Is this a correct explanation?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: Rails should remain in tension up to the maximum temperature ever expected. Otherwise they buckle and cause derailments.